# c# win32_scsicontroller drivername driverversion

Tags: c#, windows, version, driver

```
searcher = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_SCSIController");
```

The above C# statement gives me the list of controllers I'm looking for.  It also provides me with the name of the driver for each controller.  However, I also need the driver's version number, but don't see how to get it.

I've tried using searcher on the DriverName with other "Win32_*" such as Win32_PNPSignedDriver but with no luck.  The driver I was looking for was not in that list.  There must be a "Win32_*" string I'm missing.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: welcome @Ron! It's a good idea to structure your title so that it succinctly and accurately summarizes your question.

Comment: I'll do that in the future.  Thanks.

Comment: A deviceid value returned in the 1st query should appear somewhere in the second Win32_PnPSignedDriver query, is that not the case?

Comment: I went through every device returned from Win32_PnPSignedDriver and the SCSI Controllers were not in the the list.  That is, the driver names for the SCSI Controllers were not there.

Comment: I have one matching device with ID `ROOT\SPACEPORT\0000` in _SCSIController, this ID is in _PNPSignedDriver and while the driver name is missing the version number is present.

Comment: It's the driver name I need to match.  Win32_SCSIController returns 3 unique controllers.  There are repeats.  Each has it's own driver, not all the same.  I need to be able to find the correct version number for each driver.

Comment: Alex, You're right.  I didn't need to match the driver name, just the device ID.  Thanks.